# How is it possible to show svg images in component dynamically?

Tags: image, next.js

I'm using next.js, my goal is to show cards (array of images) with images on a page.
I have an issue, all my cards are shown with data, but without images. What is wrong?

My attempt.

```html
const cards = [
    { stepTitle: "Step 1:", img: "/images/faq_customer/step_1.svg", text: "Press \"Call Now\"" },
    { stepTitle: "Step 2:", img: "/images/faq_customer/step_2.svg", text: "Your phone rings" },
    { stepTitle: "Step 3:", img: "/images/faq_customer/step_3.svg", text: "You answer" },
    { stepTitle: "Step 4:", img: "/images/faq_customer/step_4.svg", text: "We call her" },
]
```

I want to show them using component

```html
const CardItem = ({ stepTitle, img, text }): JSX.Element => {
    return <div className={styles.card}>
        <h1 className={styles.card_step_title}>{stepTitle}</h1>
        <div>
            <img src={img} alt="" />
            <h1 className={styles.card_title}>{text}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

```html
 {cards.map(({ stepTitle, img, text }) => <CardItem stepTitle={stepTitle} img={img} text={text} />)}
```

Comment: Where are your images located?

Comment: The code looks fine - are you sure the images are in the `public/images/faq_customer` folder?